# In Django-Rest-Framework how can I make all requests, except GET, transactional?

Tags: python, django, transactions, django-rest-framework, django-database

According to Django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests) I can set `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` to make all requests atomic. It also states that I'm able to selectively turn it off on a "per-View" basis, not "per-View-function".

But it isn't clear if the `GET` method would also be transactional. I understand that the REST definition [considers](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) this method as `safe` and `idempotent`, thus it shouldn't ever be transactional. Specially when you think about several `GET` requests unnecessarily overloading the database.

Finally, we're using a `ListCreateView` then we cannot make the entire view non-transactional and also we cannot create a separated view just for listing because that would hurt our URLs pattern.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible.

Comment: Care to improve this answer?  What lead you to conclude it's not possible?